# framework7-cli generated app dev server doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I used the new Framework7-cli to generate a Cordova App with React presets.  When everything was finished setting up I ran `npm run start` and tried changing some code in `/pages/home.jsx`, but nothing was updated in the browser.  Does anyone know why this doesn't work right out of the box?

Here is what webpack.config.js looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');

function resolvePath(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const target = process.env.TARGET || 'web';
const isCordova = target === 'cordova';


module.exports = {
  mode: env,
  entry: [
    './src/js/app.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: resolvePath(isCordova ? 'cordova/www' : 'www'),
    filename: 'js/app.js',
    publicPath: '',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {

      '@': resolvePath('src'),
    },
  },
  devtool: env === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    contentBase: '/www/',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
    })],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolvePath('src'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7'),

          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7-react'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/template7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/dom7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/ssr-window'),
        ],
      },


      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'stylus-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
        use: [
          (env === 'development' ? 'style-loader' : {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }),
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac|m4a)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'media/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',

        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
      'process.env.TARGET': JSON.stringify(target),
    }),

    ...(env === 'production' ? [
      new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
          safe: true,
          map: { inline: false },
        },
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    ] : [
      // Development only plugins
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: env === 'production' ? {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true
      } : false,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/app.css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/static'),
        to: resolvePath(isCordova ? 'cordova/www/static' : 'www/static'),
      },
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/manifest.json'),
        to: resolvePath('www/manifest.json'),
      },
    ]),
    ...(!isCordova ? [
      new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
        swSrc: resolvePath('src/service-worker.js'),
      })
    ] : []),

  ],
};
```

And here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My App",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "framework7": {
    "cwd": "/home/david/test-react",
    "type": [
      "pwa",
      "cordova",
      "web"
    ],
    "name": "My App",
    "pkg": "io.framework7.myapp",
    "framework": "react",
    "template": "single-view",
    "cssPreProcessor": false,
    "bundler": "webpack",
    "cordova": {
      "folder": "cordova",
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine"
      ]
    },
    "webpack": {
      "developmentSourceMap": true,
      "productionSourceMap": true,
      "hashAssets": false,
      "preserveAssetsPaths": false,
      "inlineAssets": true
    },
    "theming": {
      "customColor": false,
      "color": "#007aff",
      "darkTheme": false,
      "iconFonts": true,
      "fillBars": false
    },
    "customBuild": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js",
    "build-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js",
    "build-cordova-dev": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build",
    "build-cordova-prod": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build",
    "build-cordova-ios-dev": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build ios",
    "build-cordova-ios-prod": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build ios",
    "build-cordova-android-dev": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android",
    "build-cordova-android-prod": "cross-env TARGET=cordova cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./build/build.js && cd cordova && cordova build android",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "postinstall": "cpy './node_modules/framework7-icons/fonts/*.*' './src/fonts/'"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "Android >= 5",
    "IOS >= 9.3",
    "Edge >= 15",
    "Safari >= 9.1",
    "Chrome >= 49",
    "Firefox >= 31",
    "Samsung >= 5"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "dom7": "^2.1.3",
    "framework7": "^4.5.0",
    "framework7-icons": "^2.3.1",
    "framework7-react": "^4.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "template7": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "cpy-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ora": "^3.4.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can You show us the `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan  just added it to my question

Comment: Hmm, that seems tricky and complicated. Please, can You show `package.json` too? Thank You.

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan  I included `package.json`

Comment: Have you emptied the browser cache?

Answer (score 2):

I see one little but very important problem here. In Your `package.json`-->`scripts`-->`start` You don't include some commands.

It should look like this:

```
"start": "npm run — mode development — open — hot",
```

What is going on here:

1. When You trigger `npm start`, `webpack-dev-server` is going to fire up the application in  **mode=development**.
2. Then **( — open)** displays it in your default browser automatically.
3. And finally, **( — hot)** keeps watching for any changes made to the application.

If it doesn't help You try this one:

```
"start": "npm run — mode dev — open — hot",
```

Good luck :)